# Dynamically altering CSS attributes from database

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am trying to be able to dynamically alter CSS attributes through a field in the database. I know that I could put in a bunch of if statements like this.

```
if (@Model["font"] == "arial")
//set the font to arial
```

This will work but will clutter my views. I was wondering if someone has a more elegant solution to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some good options here:

- Add a style block directly to the view (as Matthew suggests). Typically styles should go into separate files, but some of the motivation for doing so (e.g. reuse) goes away because your source is dynamic.
- You could generate/cache a stylesheet served from a controller or other HTTP handler. [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) (a [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/) preprocessing library for .Net) does exactly this; it takes a source, processes it into plain CSS, then caches the results.
- You could generate some of your HTML using a DOM in the controller, and apply the styles inline. This technique is very useful for HTML generated by WYSIWYG editors, as they often generate sub-par markup and need tweaks to be made inline.
- If you really wanted to be "fancy", you could look at integrating your model's properties into LESS CSS. I'd envision a pre-processing step that resolved model values, and then allow normal LESS pre-processing to occur (probably using dotless).

Speaking of LESS CSS, you might be able to extract all your configurable values into a different files, and just pick the right variables file based on a value in the database. This would keep the actual styles out of the database altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any additional logic, you can just output the value in the model verbatim.

```
body {
    font-family: @Model["font"]
}
```